# Accrued Interest Rate in times of Covid

Tags: interest, covid-19

I had about $3000 dollars in accrued interest prior to the Covid Forbearance period. I understand that there is no interest during this Forbearance period. I'm seeing that the accrued interest is $0 now, which I find surprising! Shouldn't it stay the same as before? It seems like they wiped out the accrued interest prior to Covid as the payments I made are going straight to the total amount due for the loan (interest + principal), which makes me think they added the accrued interest to the principal balance.

Even if they didn't do this, the amount I would pay during forbearance would decrease the overall balance by the same amount as compared to if they hadn't added the accrued interest to the principal.

However, when I resume payment in a couple of months, in the way they did it, wouldn't I be paying more overall than if they had left the accrued interest intact? I'm wondering as this seems a case of capitalization. But I could be wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume you're talking about a student loan?

Comment: yes student loan